# ERROR "Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame." When using WSPROXY's createitem with JSON object any tips?

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ssjs, wsproxy

So, I've been testing some use cases with SSJS and got into this error "Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame." which occurs with the
`apiAudiencia.createItem("DataExtensionObject", insertObject);`
. Bellow are my SSJS and the JSON it should insert into the Data Extension 'TESTE'

```js
Platform.Load("core", "1");

try {
  var insertObject =[];
  
  var objIteracao =[];
  var obj_campo_CD_CAMPA = Platform.Function.ParseJSON('{Name:"CD_CAMPA",Value:"registro CD_CAMPA"}');
  objIteracao.push(obj_campo_CD_CAMPA);
  var obj_campo_DS_EMAIL_INTLC = Platform.Function.ParseJSON('{Name:"DS_EMAIL_INTLC",Value:"registro@DS_EMAIL_INTLC.com"}');
  objIteracao.push(obj_campo_DS_EMAIL_INTLC);
  var obj_campo_JORNADA = Platform.Function.ParseJSON('{Name:"JORNADA",Value:"registro JORNADA"}');
  objIteracao.push(obj_campo_JORNADA);
  var obj_campo_CD_EC = Platform.Function.ParseJSON('{Name:"CD_EC",Value:"registro CD_EC"}');
  objIteracao.push(obj_campo_CD_EC);
  var obj_campo_DATA_ENTRADA = Platform.Function.ParseJSON('{Name:"DATA_ENTRADA",Value:"2022-08-11"}');
  objIteracao.push(obj_campo_DATA_ENTRADA);
  var obj_campo_NU_CNPJ_EMPR = Platform.Function.ParseJSON('{Name:"NU_CNPJ_EMPR",Value:"registro NU_CNPJ_EMPR"}');
  objIteracao.push(obj_campo_NU_CNPJ_EMPR);

  insertObject.push({Customerkey: 'TESTE', Properties: objIteracao});

  var apiAudiencia = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
  var res = apiAudiencia.createItem("DataExtensionObject", insertObject);
  
} catch (err) {
    Write("ERRO : " + err.message);
}
```

This is the Stringify on the insertObject:

```json
[
    {
        "Customerkey":"TESTE",
        "Properties":[
            {
                "Name":"CD_CAMPA",
                "Value":"registro CD_CAMPA"
            },
            {
                "Name":"DS_EMAIL_INTLC",
                "Value":"registro@DS_EMAIL_INTLC.com"
            },
            {
                "Name":"JORNADA",
                "Value":"registro JORNADA"
            },
            {
                "Name":"CD_EC",
                "Value":"registro CD_EC"
            },
            {
                "Name":"DATA_ENTRADA",
                "Value":"2022-08-11"
            },
            {
                "Name":"NU_CNPJ_EMPR",
                "Value":"registro NU_CNPJ_EMPR"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: The Stringify you showed at the bottom supposes to be value of objIteracao variable not insertObject variable since insertObject must have CustomerKey and Properties keys

Comment: Thanks, copied the wrong one there. I've just updated.

Answer (score 0):

SOAP/WSProxy is the long way to go about adding a row to a DE.

It's much easier with the built-in functions like [Rows.Add](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsAdd.html):

```javascript
<script runat="server" language="JavaScript">

Platform.Load("core","1");

var de = DataExtension.Init("YOURDECUSTOMERKEYHERE");

var row = {};
row.CD_CAMPA = "registro CD_CAMPA";
row.DS_EMAIL_INTLC = "registro@DS_EMAIL_INTLC.com";
row.JORNADA = "registro JORNADA"
row.CD_EC = "registro CD_EC"
row.DATA_ENTRADA = "2022-08-11"
row.NU_CNPJ_EMPR = "registro NU_CNPJ_EMPR";

var rowsAddedUpdated = 0;

try {

  rowsAddedUpdated = de.Rows.Add(row);

} catch (e) {

  Write("<br>e: " + Stringify(e));
  
}

Write("<br>rowsAddedUpdated: " + rowsAddedUpdated);

</script>
```

Comment: Hey Adam, I understand this is not the easiest way, however by what I've been reading around this should be the faster way to process, isn't it? I say that 'cause the idea is for the script to process hundreds of thousands of records every run, and the only part I'm missing right now is the data extension insert of the object. But if can't figure it out how how to fix the createItem I most probably will go back to rows.Add. Thanks!